Indices $e$ such that $\varphi_e = \varphi_{e+1}$
The problem I'm trying to solve is to prove that there are infinite indices $e \in \mathbb N_0$ such that $\varphi_e = \varphi_{e+1}$.
The fact that there exists one such $e$ is trivial, as the fixed-point theorem or the recursion theorem immediately gives us such an $e$, but I'm having trouble justifying why there is an infinite amount of such indices. I also tried to work with functions such as $f(x) = x + k$, but this did not lead me anywhere. I would certainly appreciate a hint in the right direction!

induction, modifying the fixed-point function appropriately at each step?

defining $\varphi_e$ in the question itself would make this question readable for a general audience.

The recursion theorem actually gives infinitely many fixed points. Recall the outline of the argument is that if we let $h$ be a computable function such that for all $e,$ $\varphi_{h(e)} = \varphi_{\varphi_e(e)}$ (where the right side diverges on all inputs if $\varphi_e(e)\uparrow$), and then fix an $e$ such that $\varphi_e = f\circ h,$ then $$\varphi_{h(e)} = \varphi_{\varphi_e(e)} = \varphi_{f(h(e))}$$ so $h(e)$ is a fixed point. But by the padding lemma, there are infinitely many $e$ such that $\varphi_e= f\circ h,$ and thus, since the natural choice of $h$ is injective, each gives a distinct fixed point $h(e).$
